# Clipboard sharing between the host OS and a virtual console of a VirtualBox linux guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox, console

I have a CentOS guest OS running without X11. Is there anyway I can paste text from the host clipboard into the virtual terminals or highlight text in the vt via the console mouse daemon and paste it into the host OS?

I am aware I can ssh into the guest with putty. I want to know if its possible from the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. See this outstanding request which is 6 years old already.

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/1139

Comment: Well that's annoying.

Answer (score 3):

No. Neither gpm nor the Linux kernel provide hooks for VirtualBox to inject clipboard data.